# Let users choose when close votes reset

Tags: feature-request

Often, the behavior of the close vote limit does not match well with my schedule. For example, I just ran out of close votes in the early afternoon, and cannot do any more close reviewing until this evening.

It would be more convenient, and make more sense to me, if the close votes consistently reset at e.g. 2 a.m. my local time, so that when I ran out it was for the current day, and I would always start the day with a full quota.

If I were working, I might want to have the close votes reset during my working day, so that I would have a full quota to use during the evening and early morning.

This could be implemented by having a profile entry for the reset time.

Comment: This could be very nice, but it sounds like considerable work (that is, saving an additional field in the database for every user, and running a script every hour that checks which users reset, or something similar)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum It would not necessarily have to be checked by a script. It could be checked for a given user only when the system tests whether that user has a vote available.

Answer (score 3):

**If you review every 24-hour period**

Changing when it is reset won't really help anything. You'll be limited to the same number per 24-hour period, regardless of when it is.

**If you don't review every 24-hour period**

This could be helpful here, but only if your votes reset *while voting*.

If I review in the afternoon, I would want my votes to reset while voting, effectively giving me up to *twice* the votes. Of course, I would use them up for the next day, but this only applies if you don't review every 24-hour period.

---

There are more useful ways of doing this explicitly than choosing a time for your votes to reset.

For example, you could have a limit "no more than X votes during any consecutive 24-hours".

That way, you re-aquire your close votes as you spent them, 24 hours later. There is no aribtrary clock; the clock starts when you start reviewing.

(FYI, this strategy would not be any better for your close votes if X were kept to the same number as before, but this does remove edge cases, which I think is the valuable part.)

---

This same issue applies to more important (IMO) things than close votes.

Many times, I log in to SO, give a good answer to a popular question, and see that I'm already at 190 points of my 200 point reputation cap for the "day" because of my activities the previous day (my time). :P